# Windows universal app - set focus on captureElement

Tags: mobile, win-universal-app

I have simple Win Universal app to capture photos.

When I start my app, I have some screen with button and some informations. When I press the button, I move to another page with captureElement. I wanted to use tap to capture photo and it works. However it doesnt work for first tap on that page. First tap doesnt fire "tapped" event but second and next ones work good. Can I set focus somehow on captureElement? I didnt find it for that type of control

Comment: Just tested this, I can't reproduce your problem. I tested the code on Lumia 640, OS build 10586. You can have a test with official [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit), although there is only one page, you can create a new page, and modify the code to have a test. If this is the environment problem, you can leave a comment to tell us your test device and OS build. Or please post your UI code and code behind.

Comment: Do you have some code to provide?